# Chandelier with candles

Tags: design, castle

I want to make a hanging chandelier with candles.
The centerpiece is [Technic Knob Cog](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=32072&C=115#T=S&C=115&O=%7B%22color%22:%22115%22,%22st%22:%224%22,%22ss%22:%22US%22,%22rpp%22:%22100%22,%22iconly%22:0%7D) .
My initial thought was to design it just like the [Big Ben Church bells](https://www.lego.com/cdn/product-assets/product.bi.core.pdf/6192473.pdf) (step 278).
However, I don't think that [technic pin with bar extension](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=61184&C=0#T=S&C=0&O=%7B%22color%22:%220%22,%22st%22:%224%22,%22ss%22:%22US%22,%22rpp%22:%22100%22,%22iconly%22:0%7D) will interface correctly with the technic knob cog as I think it needs an axle to hold it right? So I guess I need a way to hang a short vertical axle from a very long horizontal axle (or set of connected horizontal axles).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'll confess - my inspiration for that element in my answer to your 4 candles question came from [set 10273 - Haunted House](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=10273-1) which uses it for exactly that purpose - [instructions are here (180MB)](https://www.lego.com/cdn/product-assets/product.bi.core.pdf/6345332.pdf), it's on page 119:

[image: Knob Cog and Axle with stop instructions]

It uses a [Technic, Axle 5 with stop](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=15462#T=A) to hold the knob cog up, and it's inserted into a [Technic, Axle and Pin Connector Angled #1](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=32013#T=C) that's hanging from a beam made from [Axle Connectors 2L (Smooth)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=6538c#T=A) and Axle 2 Notched.

Comment: Good gravy, 180 MB for LEGO instructions? Wow. Thanks for noting that

Comment: Yeah, it's one big book. I thought I ought to call it out ;)

Answer (score 3):

I just realized you can put an axle through the 180 degree connectors just like you can a technic pin. Then, you just need a bush or something above the vertical axle to hold it in place.